# Honda Fit 2007 - one of the keys stopped working

Tags: honda, key, ignition-key, fit

We have two keys for this car, and both of them used to work fine until this week (mechanically, not remotely).

Now, when one of them is inserted, the green key-light turns on the dashboard... It can still open the doors, but it can no longer start the ignition. The second key works fine.

Answers [here](/questions/45556/) and [here](/questions/5847/) talk about an immobilizer problem, but if that was what happened to us too, both keys would've stopped working, wouldn't they have?

What's happening and what do we do?

Answer (score 1):

Its extremely rare the immobilizers memory only corrupts one key so its more likely a fault with the key it self.

Its not uncommon for the remote head keys to fail. Its usually from moisture getting inside. If it is a remote head key you can attempt to open it and see if it has built up corrosion. If so clean it away with isopropyl alcohol and it may start to work again. Also be sure to check the antenna on the key fobs pcb to see if the soldering is loose or cracked. It will be a long black rectangle device with or without exposed copper winding.

The transponders in non-remote keys very rarely fail but it does happen once in awhile.

I have also run into cases where the memory in the transponder itself was corrupted/rewritten, so it may can just be reprogrammed.

Other then that you can call a good local locksmith to come check it all out for you and replace if necessary. Avoid the paid listings on google.

Comment: The remote part of the key hasn't worked in a long time. But it remained perfectly functional as a regular, mechanical key. And it still opens the doors... Are you saying, the elctronic part was still playing its part, but may now be broken?

Comment: Some of the honda remote keys have keyless entry and transponder on the same pcb but they still function independently. The keyless entry is probably just because your battery in remote is dead. The transponder portion would be powered from the receiver around the ignition. Now that I think about it more tho I believe the 07 Fits have separate ceramic or glass chip (same as non-remote keys) that sits beside the keyless entry controls. If you open the back you will either see a unit take up the entire space (integrated) or you will see one with a small notch cut out in bottom corner (separate)